# Silverstripe form not showing error or success

Tags: php, validation, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have the following form,

```
public function ContactForm()
{
    $fields = FieldList::create(
        TextField::create('Nombre', 'Tu nombre')
            ->setCustomValidationMessage('Por favor coloca tu nombre.')
    );

    $actions = FieldList::create( 
        FormAction::create('sendContactForm', 'Send')
    );

    $required = [
        'Nombre',
    ];
    $validator = new RequiredFields($required);
    $form = Form::create($this, 'ContactForm', $fields, $actions, $validator);
    // I'm using this novalidate for testing 
    $form->setAttribute('novalidate', 'novalidate');
    $form->setFormMethod('POST', true);

    return $form;
}
```

And it's not giving me errors, nor success message on submit.

If I complete the field with a string, the form submits successfully and saves my data to a model, and sends an email as well, but I get no success message.

I have another page type with another form defined the same way and it works fine, I don't know why this one doesn't show me errors.

If I leave the field empty, the `sendContactForm` function is not called, the page reloads with a clean form and no errors. This makes me think the validation is working correctly because it doesn't reach the submit function, but the fact the form is coming back empty even if I add data to some fields is very strange to me, because the other form comes back with the errors and with the data previously entered.

I've also tried with no JS or CSS to make sure is not a front end interference.

They are both shown in the template using `$ContactForm` and `$MessageForm` respectively.

For reference, here are some links to the full files used for both forms/pages.

[Contact page](https://gist.github.com/ramono/f63ee278b2dfc17abb4cc72e488c3b21)

[Contact page controller](https://gist.github.com/ramono/6245e5a0fc343c80b2e557bedce5cd7c)

[Working fine form](https://gist.github.com/ramono/220465463bec74ab4d87a934b38454a9)

[Working fine form controller](https://gist.github.com/ramono/be5551ad9150aebc1cb6727f7fdb6d88)

This has been driving me nuts for hours, and I have no idea what could be wrong.